# Audio_generator keras

Tags: tensorflow, audio, keras

I am trying to classify wav files into different classes. However the number of sound files is far more than what I can load on my RAM (>10000 files). So the only optimum way I can input these files is in batches, by using a DataGenerator function (like the ImageGenerator Function & flow_from_directory). Can someone please help me with it? I have a custom spectrogram function that i would like to apply on each wav file as it is being processed.